# Автостарт VM WSL2 после запуска Windows (из состояния Stopped в состояние Running)

Tags: linux, windows, wsl2

Подскажите, может ли дистрибутив Linux WSL2 стартовать вместе с запуском Windows (в состояние Running) без использования сторонних скриптов (типа .vbs), без startup  и task scheduler? Пробовал взаимодействовать с LxssManager, ничего не вышло. Знаю, что vm на базе Hyper-v могут настраиваться с автостартом при запуске системы. Может как-то можно сделать и для vm WSL2?